# Greedy algorithm in matching students to juries that they like with an upper bound number of students each jury can check

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification, algorithms, contest-math, probabilistic-method

Recently I solved this following problem using greedy algorithm.

> There are $100$ students who participate at exam.Also there are $25$ members of jury.Each student is checked by one jury.Known that every student likes $10$ jury. Prove that we can make this every student will be checked by the jury that he likes and every jury will check at most $10$ students.

Here is my solution.

Denote $A_i \; (1 \le i \le 25)$ be the set of students that like $i$th jury and $|A_i|=a_i$.

WLOG, assume that $a_1 \le a_2 \le  \cdots \le a_{25}$. We start from $1$st jury to $25$th jury, each time pick $10$ students that like that jury, and must follow the following greedy algorithm:

1. If after we pick $10$ students from $A_i$, there still $k \le A_i-10$ students (that like $i$-th jury) left that haven't been picked. We put these students into a set $S$ in order, the latest students at the left. For example, $S= \{ G_1,G_2, \cdots , ... , G_{25} \}$ where $G_i$ is the left over students after picking $10$ from $a_i$ in $i$th jury.
2. After we pick, we exclude the jury and the students being picked (take them out from all the sets $A_i$). After excluding juries and students, we rearrange the $A_i$ and pick all the juries so $|A_j| \le 10$. This will lead to either we prove the statement or the juries left all have $|A_j| \ge 11$.
3. After finishing picking $A_{i}$, we move to pick students that like $i+1$th jury in $A_{i+1}$, but our priority is to pick as much students in $A_{i+1} \cap S$ as possible, and if there is still $h \le 10$ more students need to pick, then we pick arbitrary from $A_{i+1} \setminus S$. Remember to pick $A_{i+1} \cap S$ in order from oldest to latest (which means from $G_1$ to $G_{25}$).

Now, we need to guarantee that with this, we can always make every students be checked by the jury he/she likes. The worst case scenario is that at some point, there will be a student $X$ remaining that doesn't like any jury remaining. If that happens, consider $10$ juries that $X$ likes, denote their set to be $B_i \; (1 \le i \le 10)$ with $|B_i|=b_i$ and $b_1 \le b_2 \le  \cdots \le b_{10}$. This means $10<b_i$ (otherwise $X$ will be picked by some $i$th jury with $b_i \le 10$).

Condition 2 of the algorithm guarantees that we can always bring back to a situation that all the juries have $|B_i| \ge 11$.

Next, after jury with $B_1$ picks students, then student $X$ must be left out so $X$ is in $S$. After jury with $B_2$ picks students, since out priority is $B_2 \cap S$, so there must be exactly $10$ students + student $X$ who like jury $B_2$ in $S$ (from condition 2 and optimal picking of $B_2 \cap S$ in condition 3). After picking $B_2$, those $10$ students that like $B_2$ will be picked, hence similarly, there will be $10$ more students in $S$ that like jury $B_3$. If there is no jury $A_j$ between $B_i,B_{i+1}$ (means $|B_i| \le |A_j| \le |B_{i+1}|$) then this will continue until jury with $B_{10}$ and we find that $|S| \ge 10\cdot 9+1=91$ at stage after picking students for jury $B_1$. This is obviously a contradiction since $|B_1| \ge 11$ so that means after picking $10$ students that likes jury $B_1$, we must have $|S| \le 90$.

If there is a jury $A_j$ between some $B_i,B_{i+1}$ then from the oldest to latest rule in condition 3, we find that this won't affect that $|S| \ge 91$ at stage picking $10$ from $B_1$ (otherwise, if there is no $10$ students that like $B_{i+1}$ in $S$ at stage after picking $10$ from $B_1$, according to oldest, latest rule, we must pick student $X$ who like $B_{i+1}$ because $X$ is in older group).

Thus, the scenario that student $X$ can't find jury he/she like cannot happen. In other words, this algorithm works.  $\square$

My main question is:

> Is this solution correct?

**Comment.** For a) by using Probabilistic method, we can guarantee picking $8$ juries so each student likes at least one jury. Indeed, pick $8$ juries randomly, the probability that a student doesn't like all $8$ juries is $\frac{\binom{15}{8}}{\binom{25}{8}}$. Hence, if $X$ be the number of students that don't like all $8$ juries, according to Linearity of Expected value, we have $\mathbb{E}[X]= 100 \cdot \frac{\binom{15}{8}}{\binom{25}{8}}<1$. Thus, there exists way to pick $8$ juries so $\mathbb{E}[X]=0$, or no students that don't like all $8$ juries. I don't think probabilistic method can't prove for $7$ juries because $100 \cdot \frac{\binom{15}{7}}{\binom{25}{7}} >1$.

Comment: @JohnWatson (a) is Prove that we can select $7$ jury such that any student likes at least one jury.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I read your proof and I believe it is correct.

As a minor nit, it isn't right to say the algorithm will "each time pick $10$ students" - it might pick fewer in step 2.

The argument can be simplified substantially. Once you have defined $b_1,\dots,b_{10}$, we know there must have been $10$ other students picked from each $B_i$ instead of student $X$. That makes $100$ other students picked. But together with $X$ that makes at least $101$ students, more than the total student population.

Note the proof of correctness then doesn't even depend on any kind of ordering or prioritizing $S$ - you can just repeatedly pick any juror, assign as many students as possible to that juror, remove all the assigned people, and repeat until done.

---

For the bonus question (a), you can argue as follows:

- For any $100$ students each liking $10$ of $25$ jurors, some juror is liked by at least $\lceil 10 * 100 / 25\rceil = 40$ students, leaving at most $60.$
- For any $60$ students each liking $10$ of $24$ jurors, some juror is liked by at least $\lceil 10 * 60 / 24\rceil = 25$ students, leaving at most $35.$
- For any $35$ students each liking $10$ of $23$ jurors, some juror is liked by at least $\lceil 10 * 35 / 23\rceil = 16$ students, leaving at most $19.$
- For any $19$ students each liking $10$ of $22$ jurors, some juror is liked by at least $\lceil 10 * 19 / 22\rceil = 9$ students, leaving at most $10.$
- For any $10$ students each liking $10$ of $21$ jurors, some juror is liked by at least $\lceil 10 * 10 / 21\rceil = 5$ students, leaving at most $5.$
- For any $5$ students each liking $10$ of $20$ jurors, some juror is liked by at least $\lceil 10 * 5 / 20\rceil = 3$ students, leaving at most $2.$
- For any $2$ students each liking $10$ of $19$ jurors, some juror is liked by at least $\lceil 10 * 2 / 19\rceil = 2$ students, leaving none.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if the following is correct proof? Can someone check please. (I need a jury!)

Take first $25$ students. Take any subset $X$ of this students and let $Y$ be the set of jury the students in $X$ like. Then since each student likes exactly $10$ jury and each jury checks at most $10$ students, we have for $ 10|X|\leq 10|Y|$ so $|X|\leq |Y|$ and Hall condition is fulfilled and thus we have a perfect matching. So each jury checks exactly 1 student.

We repeat this with next $25$ students and again we have perfect matching. So now each jury checks exactly $2$ students. We repeat this two more times, so each jury checks exactly $4<10$ students and each student is checked by jury he likes.